# Get the value from SCEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sceditor

I'm trying to get the value from my SCEditor textarea, using this code:

```
var fbeschreibung = '';
$(function() {
    // Replace all textarea's
    // with SCEditor
    $("textarea").sceditor({
        plugins: "bbcode",
        style: "css/style.less",
        width: "100%",
        toolbar:"bold,italic,underline,strike,subscript,superscript|left,center,right,justify|size,color,removeformat|bulletlist,orderedlist,horizontalrule,emoticon",
        locale:"de" ,
        resizeEnabled:false
    });
    fbeschreibung = $('textarea').sceditor('instance').val();
    $('textarea').sceditor('instance').val('Hello [b]World![/b]');
});
```

I then want to send the value via AJAX:

```
$.post('saveprofile.php', 
   {fbeschreibung : fbeschreibung},
   function (response) {
      alert(response);
   }
);
```

However, I'm not able to get this to work. I haven't found find any tips in the documentation: http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/val/

My variable `fbeschreibung` is just empty. Is there something I've done wrong?

Comment: For starters, use a selector that selects a single element. E.g. `$('textarea').first()`.

Comment: See the docs: https://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/val/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$(function() {
    // Replace all textarea's
    // with SCEditor
    var fbeschreibung = $("textarea").sceditor({
        plugins: "bbcode",
        style: "css/style.less",
        width: "100%",
        toolbar:"bold,italic,underline,strike,subscript,superscript|left,center,right,justify|size,color,removeformat|bulletlist,orderedlist,horizontalrule,emoticon",
        locale:"de" ,
        resizeEnabled:false
    }).sceditor('instance');
    var value = fbeschreibung.getBody().html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this particular editor, but the options (comments) I provided you may work.

```
var fbeschreibung = '';
$(function() {
    // Replace all textarea's
    // with SCEditor
    var editor = $("textarea").sceditor({
        plugins: "bbcode",
        style: "css/style.less",
        width: "100%",
        toolbar:"bold,italic,underline,strike,subscript,superscript|left,center,right,justify|size,color,removeformat|bulletlist,orderedlist,horizontalrule,emoticon",
        locale:"de" ,
        resizeEnabled:false
    });
    /* Try the following 3 options */

    fbeschreibung = editor.val();
    fbeschreibung = editor.getSourceEditorValue();
    fbeschreibung = editor.getWysiwygEditorValue();

    editor.val('Hello [b]World![/b]');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunatly it doesnt work :/ first options: nothing happens. Second and third option gives me the error: editor.getSourceEditorValue is not a function

But thank you anyway :)

Comment: I am so sorry. I realized I made a very stupid mistake. I set the editor variable to the wrapping function and not to the editor element. I just edited, try it again!

Comment: same result :/ and np at least we try to solve this ;)

Comment: Try creating a fiddle, it would be easier to solve and to get help!

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing some issues getting the JQuery code for this to work, and found that this can actually be done without using JQuery at all using:

```
sceditor.instance(textarea).val()
```

Where `textarea` is the textarea that your editor was created from:

```
let textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');

// the sceditor variable is created by importing the sceditor JavaScript code
// (sceditor.min.js and formats/bbcode.js)
sceditor.create(textarea, {
    format: 'bbcode',
    style: '/minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
});

function logEditorValue(){
   let textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
   let value = sceditor.instance(textarea).val();

   console.log(value); // prints the value of the sceditor
}
```

If you have multiple SCEditors on the page, you can just use pass a different `textarea` to the `sceditor.instance` function

<sub>(More info on the [Usage section on SCEditor's GitHub](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor#usage))</sub>